Waldhausen S-construction for exact categories
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an exact category. Then, we can consider $\mathcal{C}$ as a Waldhausen category, where the cofibrations are admissible monomorphisms. By Waldhausen $S$-construction we know that $S_n(\mathcal{C})$ is also a Waldhausen category. Does the Waldhausen construction imply that $S_n\mathcal{C}$ is also an exact category? If yes, what are admissible monomorphisms and admissible epimorphisms in $S_n(\mathcal{C})$? If not, is there any known structure on $S_n(\mathcal{C})$ to make it an exact category?

Let me add to Tim's answer that this also holds when suitably defining all of those terms in the higher categorical context, as does Barwick in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5232. Remark also that there is nothing to construct: it is a property of a Waldhausen category to be an exact category by Corollary 4.8.1 of Barwick's paper.
In fact, in 4.9, Barwick gives the conditions for the Waldhausen structure to be exact, and in this case, they should not be too hard to check, using notably the description of the Waldhausen structure of $S_n\mathcal{C}$ given in 5.15, though I reckon Tim's way is probably faster.

Ah nice! That's much more complete

Hi again Victor! I was working on $S_2(\mathcal{C})$ for a given exact infinity category $\mathcal{C}$. The last two conditions in 4.9 (as you mentioned) are satisfied for $S_2(\mathcal{C})$. But, how can we prove the first condition? In fact, why is "the map from the direct sum of the two first objects of given exact sequences to the direct sum of second objects in each exact sequence" a cofibration? I mean let's say $X \to Y \to Z$ and $X' \to Y' \to Z'$ are objects of $S_2(\mathcal{C})$. then, why is the induced map $X \oplus Y \to X' \oplus Y'$ a cofibration in $\mathcal{C}$? any ideas?

I imagine you mean why $X\oplus X'\to Y\oplus Y'$ is a cofibration? To see this, you can factor it as $X\oplus X'\to Y\oplus X'\to Y\oplus Y'$ where the first map is of the form $(i, \mathrm{id})$ and the second $(\mathrm{id}, i')$. Those two maps are cofibrations by stability under pushout of cofibrations, so this shows that direct sums in $S_2(\mathcal{C})$ are computed as in the functor category $\mathrm{Fun}([2], \mathcal{C})$, but the former is a full subcategory of the latter, so $S_2(\mathcal{C})$ itself must be additive (both have the same shear map).

Sorry! That was a stupid question I asked! :D thanks!

There is no such thing as a stupid question ;) I did not think of the above argument immediately either

Yes, if $\mathcal C$ is a Quillen-exact category, then the Waldhausen category $S_n(\mathcal C)$ is also a Quillen-exact category. The admissible monos are the Waldhausen cofibrations, and the admissible epis are the admissible monos of $S_n(\mathcal C^{op})$ as you'd expect.
To see this, recall that a morphism $f_\bullet : (X_0 \rightarrowtail \cdots \rightarrowtail X_n) \to (Y_0 \rightarrowtail \cdots \rightarrowtail Y_n)$ in $S_n(\mathcal C)$ is a cofibration if $f_1, \dots, f_n$ are cofibrations and every naturality square $(X_n \to X_{n+1}) \to (Y_n \to Y_{n+1})$ has a cofibration comparison map $Y_n \cup_{X_n} X_{n+1} \to Y_{n+1}$. If $\mathcal C$ is Quillen exact, and hence an extension-closed subcategory of an abelian category $\mathcal D$, then this is equivalent to saying that each of these naturality squares is a pullback square in $\mathcal D$, or equivalently that the maps between the cokernels $X_{n+1}/X_n \to Y_{n+1} /Y_n$ are monomorphisms in $\mathcal D$. From this we can see that $f$ is a cofibration iff $f_{ij}: X_{ij} \to Y_{ij}$ is a monomorphism in $\mathcal D$ for each $i\leq j$ (using the full staircase diagram now rather than just the filtration). Dually, $f$ is a cofibration in $S_n (\mathcal C^{op})$ iff $f_{ij}$ is an epimorphism in $\mathcal D$ for each $i \leq j$. Therefore, to see that this gives a Quillen exact structure on $S_n(\mathcal C)$, it will suffice to show that $S_n(\mathcal C)$ is closed under extensions in the abelian category $Fun(Fun([n], [n]) , \mathcal D)$ of all staircase diagrams. If $X_\bullet , Y_\bullet \in S_n(\mathcal C)$ and $Z_\bullet \in Fun(Fun([n], [n]), \mathcal D)$ is an extension, then $Z_{ij} \in \mathcal C$ for all $i \leq j$ simply because $\mathcal C$ is extension-closed in $\mathcal D$. To see that $Z_\bullet$ satisfies the requisite exactness properties to lie in $S_n(\mathcal C)$, I think it suffices to repeatedly use the fact that if you have a 3 x 3 grid in an abelian category and 5 of the 6 sequences appearing are short exact, then so is the remaining one (that's the 9 lemma, right?).

Hi Tim! I still am struggling with one of the statements in your comment. Let me consider the simple case $S_2(\mathcal{C})$. You mentioned that assuming $\mathcal{C}$ is an exact category, $f:X \to Y$ is a cofibration iff
$f_{ij} : X_{ij} \to Y_{ij}$ is a cofibration in $\mathcal{C}$. I don't see why the other condition  "$Y_{01} \cup_{X_{01}} X_{02} \to Y_{02}$ is a cofibrations" drops here! I am not sure if I understand is correctly. Is there any reference for this so that I can take a look? Or, could you guide me a little bit about it please? Thanks

I mean does assuming that all $f_{ij} : X_{ij} \to Y_{ij}$ are cofibrations , automatically imply that the map $Y_{01} \cup_{X_{01}} X_{02} \to Y_{02}$ is a cofibration in $\mathcal{C}$? I'm again assuming the case $n=2$.

@ArashKarimi I'm using the following fact: Let $A \rightrightarrows B , C \rightrightarrows D$ be a commutative square of monomorphisms in an abelian category. Then the following are equivalent : (1) $B \cup_A C \to D$ is a monomorphism, (2) the square is a pullback (3) $B / A \to D / C$ is a monomorphism (or (4) symmetrically, $C/A \to D/B$ is a monomorphism). This is the kind of statement which can be puzzled through easily enough in a module category, and then generalizes to any abelian category by the embedding theorem (though it shouldn't be so bad to give an elementary proof)

Thank you Tim! Can this proposition be found in some paper, or textbook? I mean, do you know if there is any reference with such proposition?

I’m sure it’s in many references. I feel pretty confident  I could find this in Freyd s Abelian categories. It’s basically the nth isomorphism theorem for some value of n.
